# XPath SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, xpath

How do I actually run XPath algorithms? Can I run it directly in SQL Server 2008? If so how?

Even something basic like `/bookstore/*`

Selects all the child nodes of the bookstore element, and maybe print them out or return them

Please help! I'm having issues finding tutorials/examples.

[SQL Server 2008 XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676271/sql-server-2008-xpath)
[XPath to fetch SQL XML value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890923/xpath-to-fetch-sql-xml-value)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [XQuery Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx). And under tag [xquery-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xquery-sql) you find a couple of question regarding XQuery in SQL Server that might be helpful. They also hide under [sqlxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlxml).

You could also have a look at [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can find some good examples here

- List item
  [XQUERY,XPATH,XMLSCHEMA,XML INDEX](http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2012/09/xqueryxpathxmlschemaxml-index_6.html)
- List item
  [XPATH Tutorials Examples](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/examples.html)